# How to show Collection in iPad but List in iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, ipad

I have a requirement to show the Data in Linear Vertical List in iPhone and
in Collection/Grid in IPAD

In the iPhone, it should look like

[image]

But In Ipad, it should look like

[image]

I have already implemented in iPhone through table view but don't know how to show it as grid view in IPAD

Here are my questions

1. should I have to create the Separate view controller for Ipad if yes
   then how can I define two view controller one for iPhone and other
   for iPad
2. what is the best way to achieve this?

please help me I am trying to implement it but can not find any way.

(Note)Images are copied from Vimeo iTunes app https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/vimeo/id425194759?mt=8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create two different controller's for `IPAD` and `IPHONE`. Just create one controller with `UICollectionView` and then use `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` for your `UICollectionView` to set layout of `UICollectionView` according to the device weather it is `IPAD` or `IPHONE` Try this solution if you have any doubt pls let us know.

Try this solution

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *collectionViewFlowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
[collectionViewFlowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
self.myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = collectionViewFlowLayout;
```

Also you can use multiple properties of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`.

Check this solution and let me know if it works for you.

Check these links for reference :

1. https://www.raywenderlich.com/136159/uicollectionview-tutorial-getting-started
2. https://www.raywenderlich.com/107439/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest

Comment: how to use UICollectionViewFlowLayout to set the listing as grid in Ipad and Linear vertical list in iPhone? and can you provide me link to any sample or tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this is with Adaptive Layout and size classes in the storyboard. You don’t need to write any code at all, and you  are also covered for multitasking/split-screen and future iOS devices of unknown dimensions. You can make any view appear or disappear according to weather the width is compact (like the iPhone) or regular (like the iPad). In the views inspector you can add a variation for compact width like this:

[Adding a compact width variation to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyIYq.png)

Click add variation and untick “installed”. Now that view will only be installed when the device has compact width. You can do this with a container view with an embed segue to a UITableViewController.

If you view the storyboard as an iPad ( by clicking the little icons at the bottom where it says “view as”) that view will disappear. Replace with another container view that segues to UICollectionViewController and do the same again, but this time add a variation with regular width.

Thats it.

(Sorry, I don't have enough points to show images)

Here is a [Demo project](https://github.com/quantumOrange/AdaptiveLayoutDemo) that creates something like the layout and behaviour you want. All the action is in the storyboard, the view controllers are just  skeletons.